# Track emails send using SendGrid

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I am using SendGrid to send emails but now I need to track emails activity when a user open a email / read or archived, I need to get email status return into my web and save it to database. If anyone have knowledge about it or idea, please suggest.

Comment: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Webhooks/event.html

Comment: @parveen you just have to deserialize response and check the property "delivered" status

Comment: Thanks guys got the solution https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook/